# json schema to validate property value with its dynamic key

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

data:

```
{
  "dynamic_key_1": {
    "key1": "value1"
    "id": "dynamic_key_1"
  },
  "dynamic_key_2": {
    "key1": "value2"
    "id": "some_random"
  }
}
```

schema:

```
{
    "patternProperties": {
      "^[^{}\"/\\\\]+$": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "id"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "string"
            // ... validate with key
          }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

How to validate the `id` value to equal it's `key` using json schema.

In above case the `dynamic_key_1` would pass and `dynamic_key_2` would fail the test.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this in JSON Schema unless you know all possible values upfront. You cannot dynamically use data from the instance as some sort of template in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a way to do this. Used `patternNames` regex to validate.

```
...
"propertyNames": {
    "pattern": "[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_-]*$"
  },
"patternProperties": {
      "^[^{}\"/\\\\]+$": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "id"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "string"
            // ... validate with key
          }
        }
     }
  }
...
```